# Macbook M1 and external monitor/docking stations. Crashes and weird behaviors

Tags: safari, dock, apple-silicon

I'm a happy Macbook M1 (Monterrey) user for almost a year now.
Happy when I use my mac by itself.
When I plug it into my USB docking station (Plugable USB 3.0 Universal Laptop Docking Station Dual Monitor, https://plugable.com/products/ud-3900), everything changes (I use it without any issue on Windows this docking station for a couple of years).
The weirdest behavior is that every time I open a web page with Safari (I'm writing with Chrome now), the page opens, but after a few seconds, I keep getting:

> A problem repeatedly occurred with ....

This is the easiest issue to explain, but in general, I have the feeling the system is not as snap and "solid" as it is when used by itself. To be honest it doesn't make a lot of sense.

I have too little info to provide, I would rather need help to start troubleshooting from somewhere.
Logs to look? tools to use to investigate?

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Thanks!

ps: I read everywhere that 2 monitors are not supported, but I can see and use 2 monitor with the dock. Can be this related to the issue?

Comment: Please edit your question, or add as a comment, the _specific_ USB docking station you are using. There are an infinitude of models available, with many (IMHO) of dubious quality, and some which are labeled macOS compatible, but aren't. Also - what other devices are connected to thus USB docking station? Does the problem occur when _only_ the docking station is connected?

Comment: @IconDaemon I'll edit the question, but about the "occur when only the docking station is connected", I was pretty clear in saying that

Comment: What version of macOS are you running?

Comment: @pion You are right. I'm running Monterrey

Comment: More specifically, what version number? Are you on 12.1?

Comment: @pion Yes, 12.1

Comment: What kind of adapter are you connecting to the USB3 (blue A-port) on the Plugable Dock to convert to USBC? The Plugable does not have USBC ports.

Comment: I'm using the Syntec USB C TO USB 3.0 ADAPTER ( https://syntechhome.com/collections/adapter/products/usb-c-to-usb-adapter-1). It is the same I use for my windows laptop (that works fine)

Comment: Check to see if you are using the power supply for this dock, and not for some other powered device by accident. From my experience, docks should be able to pass through data and USB power from the Mac without being connected to a power source. Try the dock disconnected to the power supply and read & write some data from a USB flash drive to test. Additionally, if you have, or can get access to, a [multimeter](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-multimeter/all), you should test to make sure the power supply is actually putting out the correct 5 volts @ 4 amps.